# Consuming WebAPI JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build some kind of RESTful-like API, I'm aware of that my first draft probably isn't anything near the real RESTful design pattern. However my real question is how should I consume my service using JSON?

In my so called real world example I want my users to sign in via the service so I have this AuthenticationController

```
namespace RESTfulService.Controllers
{
    public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
    {

        public string Get(string username, string password)
        {
            // return JSON-object or JSON-status message
            return "";
        }

        public string Get()
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

Considering the increasing popularity with the technology I assumed that very little code would be needed for consuming the service. Do I really need to serialize the JSON manually with some kind of third party package like json.net? Beneath is my draft for the client

```
private static bool DoAuthentication(string username, string password)
{
    var client = InitializeHttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("/api/rest/authentication").Result;  
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        //retrieve JSON-object or JSON-status message

    }
    else
    {
        // Error
    }

    return true;
}

private static HttpClient InitializeHttpClient()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");

    // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    return client;
}
```

How do I send JSON from service and how do I interpreting it on the client?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but for consuming REST services you should have a look at RestSharp.

Comment: Yes I have been looking into that but I was "hoping" for some code that did not depend on third party.

Comment: On the server side, Web API will automatically serialize the return value (to JSON, if that's what the client requests). Have you looked at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api?

Comment: If it's JSON you want, you should be able to get it out of the box, as WebApi already has a dependency on JSON.Net library exactly for this purpose. Return the object that you want serialized from the controller method. And in the Client code just request it with `Accept application/json` (HttpClient is fine, you don't need RestSharp if you don't want to use it). Have you tried it to get your code working at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions.aspx) in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll.  As explained [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#MediaTypeFormatters) (and suggested by Mike Wasson in a comment above), you can call ReadAsAsync<T>() on the response content to deserialize from JSON (or XML) to a CLR type:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var myObject = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>();
}
```

If you need to customize the deserialization, that article links to a further explanation of MediaTypeFormatters.